# How do I collect ALL output from pexpect.spawn()

Tags: python-3.x, pexpect

Currently the c.read() function only returns values from output of the program that I am calling and does not collect what happens during the interactive portion.  (**In other words**:  Waiting for user name and password).  Since errors can happen during that section I need to collect all output after the cmd is called.

Using the run command works fine.  I am trying to convert to using expect.spawn() since that looks very close to the ssh version of expect.  Current the run() method works fine in that it works locally.  I can't find getOutput() type function that would return the entire output.

```
import pexpect
class Expect( ):
    def Do( self, cmd, program: list = [], timeout: int = 20 ):
        # result = run( cmd, events=program, timeout=timeout).decode() 

        result = ''
        c = pexpect.spawn( cmd, encoding='utf-8', timeout=timeout )
        for curItem in program:
            # print( 'wait: ' + curItem[0] + ' resp: ' + curItem[1])
            c.expect( curItem[0] )
            c.sendline( curItem[1] )
            # result += c.read()
    
        result += c.read()

        print ( 'res: ' + str(result) )
        return result


cmd  = 'fmsadmin list files -s'
prog = [('username \\(.+\\):', 'yourUN\n'), ('password:', 'yourPW\n')]
res  = Expect().Do( cmd, prog )    # Returns everything
# use results to verify functionality
```

**Results**

```
ID File                  Clients Size   Status Enabled Extended Privileges                                                                   Encrypted 
1  FMServer_Sample.fmp12 0       905216 Normal fmapp fmxml fmphp fmwebdirect                                                                 No
```

**When I expect**

```
username (yourUN):yourUN
password:
ID File                  Clients Size   Status Enabled Extended Privileges                                                                   Encrypted 
1  FMServer_Sample.fmp12 0       905216 Normal fmapp fmxml fmphp fmwebdirect                                                                 No
```

**Update**

I added result += c.before + c.after just under c.sendline( curItem[1] ) which now returns:
c.sendline( curItem[1] )

```
username (yourUN): yourUN

password:
ID File                  Clients Size   Status Enabled Extended Privileges                                                                   Encrypted 
1  FMServer_Sample.fmp12 0       905216 Normal fmapp fmxml fmphp fmwebdirect                                                                 No
```

Unfortunately there are still two issues. 1 there are additional values such as returns in the output and if I provide an invalid password I get debugging details back without the apps returned values.  I get:

```
before (last 100 chars): '\r\n/usr/local/bin/fmsadmin: Permission denied, please try again.\r\nusername (yourUN):'
after: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT'>
match: None
match_index: None
etc
```

So in short, I'm looking for the full returned values from the CLI exactly as it would be returned if I did it by hand.  Which is what run() does.

Comment: I added: result += c.before + c.after at bottom of for statement but this seams like a hack AND it is adding additional returns some cases.  Getting an extra return after my account but not after the password.

Comment: Also getting unnecessary debugging detail that run() did not return:  after: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT'>
match: None
match_index: None

Comment: Adding c.exitstatus = False or True does not work to remove the debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.  Not quite expected but it makes sense.  Several changes:

1. Add result += c.before + c.after at end of for loop.  This captures
   output from from the account and password and any error from the CLI
   application.
2. Put the spawn, expect, send inside a try accept block
3. Move result += c.read() inside Try before Except (quiet the
   exception)
4. Finally call result += c.buffer during the exception.

I'll probably remove the local section in next version (once I figure out remote case)

```
from pexpect import *

class Expect( ):
    def Do( self, cmd, program: list = [], timeout: int = 20 ):
        local   = False
        result  = ''
        if local:
            result = runu( cmd, events=program, timeout=timeout ) 
        else:
            c = ''
            try:
                c = spawnu( cmd, timeout=timeout )
                for curItem in program:
                    c.expect( curItem[0] )
                    c.sendline( curItem[1] )
                    result += c.before + c.after
                result += c.read()
            except:
                result += c.buffer
        return result

cmd  = 'fmsadmin list files -s'
prog = [('username \\(.+\\):', 'yourUN\n'), ('password:', 'yourPW\n')]
res  = Expect().Do( cmd, prog, 5 )
print ( '-' * 50 + '\n' + str(res))
```

Answer (score 1):

Pexpect, just like original TCL Expect, is kinda tricky to get the correct portions of session inputs and outputs. The challenge is to format your search patterns to match what it should, and only that. Getting this to work correctly, all you have to do is to parse the [returned object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) with `before`, `after` and `match` attributes.

That said, Pexpect gets everything the terminal shows, including commands and outputs. Fortunately, passwords are not shown so, unfortunately, Pexpect can't see them.

```
from pexpect import spawn, EOF  # Better import only needed methods
process = spawn('bash', encoding='utf-8')
process.expect('$')             # Expects terminal prompt

process.sendline('read -p "username: " var')
process.expect('\nusername: ')  # Gets command, newline and username prompt
process.sendline('me')
process.expect('[^\n]*\n.*$')   # Gets typed string, newlind and terminal prompt
print(process.match.group(0))   # Prints whole string matched
me                              # User typed
me@myhost ~ $                   # Terminal prompt

process.sendline('read -sp "password: " var')   # Note the '-s' for 'silent'
process.expect('\npassword: ')
process.sendline('my_passwd')
process.expect('.*$')           # Trying to match a newline just doesn't work
print(process.match.group(0))
me@myhost ~ $                   # Only terminal prompt

process.sendline('exit')
process.expect(EOF)
```

So what you should know is what kind of problem you want to solve. Why do you want to collect absolutely everything sent and returned, including the password?

BTW 1, you might already know the issue with your plain password in the code. My recommendation: `getpass`:

```
from getpass import getpass
password = getpass()
<Then use the password>
```

BTW 2, just in case, have the [docs](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) around.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here.  I didn't have an issue getting program to work.  It found and responded correctly to the user name and password.  Unfortunately, I didn't not get all of the response back.  The account name and password details where not included in the response.  Later on I found providing an invalid password I get Pexcept's debugging information instead of the CLI's output from the program.  Only a partial CLI output is in the buffer.

Comment: I rewrote the original article to include actual and expected results so you can SEE the issue.  Oh this is NOT production code so I'm not worried about the account details and OMG I have read the docs about 5 times since last Thursday so I do appreciate your help.

Comment: It appears I missed your question.  "Why do I want to collect everything."  I'm testing software.  So I need EVERYTHING caught so that I can verify that the software is responding correctly.

Comment: @Keith Well, I did my best to understand your question. You said you wanted to collect all inputs and outputs, but couldn't get the password sent. I pointed out why Pexpect doesn't do it in normal usage, a security issue in doing so, and a safer way of dealing with that. But your edit shows that the output you want doesn't show the password, so I'll just accept your feeling that I can't understand it.

Comment: @Keith Your question doesn't mention this is test code that won't go into production, nor the docs you read before my answer. So I thought mentioning the security issue and the official docs would be of help. If you think it's a bad idea, pls just ignore that part - it might help future readers. As a side note, Pexpect doesn't require reading all bytes sent to validate the code. At least I never had to - but what do I know?

Comment: @Keith One last thing: Pexpect *always* returns debug information when there's an error, so what you saw is exactly what you should see. IMHO, you'd better work on your code to process possible outputs, instead of letting it generate exceptions and "quieting" them. But, again, it's just my way. You know what's better for you.

Comment: Everything is good.  I tend to put to much detail in these articles and people get overloaded.  I've been trying to back off a bit.  In this case the test code is trying to test an application with positive and negative test cases. I have to quiet the exceptions.  From an SQA stand point that is a requirement.  This allows me to test the response of the application I'm testing.  I've written a single class that can handle both local and remote cases so I can test in my office or remotely.  This one is a done deal so TYVM!!

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried logfile and I was able to capture everything including password

```
process = spawn('bash', encoding='utf-8')
process.logfile = sys.stdout
```

https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html